# Floating point addition algorithm

Tags: rust, floating-point

I made a function in Rust to add two floating point numbers (`f32`s) together using only their bit representation and integer operations. I have tested it for a quite a few different cases but I'm not sure how I can efficiently test it for all floating point numbers without it taking ages.

````rs
fn add_f32(mut a: f32, mut b: f32) -> f32 {
    if b > a {
        // If b has a larger exponent than a, swap a and b so that a has the larger exponent
        core::mem::swap(&mut a, &mut b);
    }

    let a_normal = a.is_normal();
    let b_normal = b.is_normal();

    let a_bits = a.to_bits();
    let b_bits = b.to_bits();
    let mut a_exp = (a_bits << 1) >> (23 + 1);
    let mut b_exp = (b_bits << 1) >> (23 + 1);
    
    let mut a_mant = a_bits & 0x007fffff;
    let mut b_mant = b_bits & 0x007fffff;

    if a_exp == 0 {
        a_exp += 1;
    }
    if b_exp == 0 {
        b_exp += 1;
    }

    let exp_diff = a_exp - b_exp;

    let sticky_bit = b_mant.trailing_zeros() + 1 < exp_diff;

    // Add the implicit leading 1 bit to the mantissas
    if a_normal {
        a_mant |= 1 << 23;
    }
    if b_normal {
        b_mant |= 1 << 23;
    }

    // Append extra bits to the mantissas to ensure correct rounding
    a_mant <<= 2;
    b_mant <<= 2;

    // If the shift causes an overflow, the b_mant is too small so is set to 0
    b_mant = b_mant.checked_shr(exp_diff).unwrap_or(0);

    if sticky_bit {
        b_mant |= 1;
    }

    let mut mant = a_mant + b_mant;

    let overflow = (mant >> 26) != 0;
    if !overflow {
        if mant & 0b11 == 0b11 {
            mant += 0b100;
            if (mant >> 26) != 0 {
                mant >>= 1;
                a_exp += 1;
            }
        } else if mant & 0b110 == 0b110 {
            mant += 0b100;
            if (mant >> 26) != 0 {
                mant >>= 1;
                a_exp += 1;
            }
        }
    } else {
        match mant & 0b111 {
            0b111 | 0b110 | 0b101 => {
                mant += 0b1000;
            },
            0b100 => {
                if mant & 0b1000 == 0b1000 {
                    mant += 0b1000;
                }
            },
            _ => {},
        }
        
        mant >>= 1;
        a_exp += 1;
    }

    mant >>= 2;

    if mant >> 23 == 0 {
        a_exp = 0;
    } else {
        mant <<= 9;
        mant >>= 9;
    }
    
    f32::from_bits(mant | (a_exp << 23))
}
```
````

Comment: Did you finally checked this (nice) code ?

Comment: @JCLL Yes, I tested it a while ago and completely forgot to update the post! It works so long as `a` and `b` are finite (also can't be `NaN`), both have positive sign, and as long as `a + b` is not infinite. Obviously the code can be easily modified to account for these cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tested it for a quite a few different cases but I'm not sure how I can efficiently test it for all floating point numbers
> without it taking ages.

I would use something like the [quickcheck crate](https://docs.rs/quickcheck/latest/quickcheck/) (a port of Haskell's QuickCheck) to test the property of whether your addition function has the same results as ordinary f32 addition. If you don't know what quickcheck is, then [this video might help](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P4iyEX-4kYI).

Fuzzing your function as described in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qUu1vJNg8yo) about Fuzz-Driven Development (FDD) might be another option.